# Null Pointer Exception with entrySet() on HashMap

Tags: java

I want to iterate through the HashMap and this is part of the code:

```
HashMap<Long, Integer> users = ((HashMap<Long, Integer>) getArguments().getSerializable("HashMap"));

Iterator it = users.entrySet().iterator();
```

> 04-25 19:13:31.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.util.Set java.util.HashMap.entrySet()' on a null object
>   reference

I looked at the users variable and it does contain a table with keys and values.

Comment: Please update the question with a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: It's obvious `users` is `null` but we dont know why with the information given.

Comment: `getArguments().getSerializable("HashMap")` is returning a `null`. You have to find out why that is so the second line does not case NPE exception.

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate.  If you can prove beyond a shadow of a doubt that `users` isn't null, then I'll be happy to reopen this.